# How to avoid processes to steal focus from C# application?

Tags: c#, process, focus

I'm having some problems starting multiple processes sequentially in C#. These processes I'm trying to start spend just 30 seconds more or less to finish his procedure. And I don't want these processes stealing focus from any app. I've tried two approaches (the following codes are into a looping statement):

```
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "References\\InclinacaoHGrid.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = i.ToString() + " " + j.ToString() + " " +
                                        valA + " " + valS + " " + valP + " " + pathNodes;
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
myProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(myProcess_OutputDataReceived);
myProcess.Start();
myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

And using Interaction.Shell with the parameter "AppWinStyle.MinimizedNoFocus":

```
int pid = Interaction.Shell("References\\InclinacaoHGrid.exe " + i.ToString() + " " + j.ToString() + " " +
                                        valA + " " + valS + " " + valP + " " + pathNodes, AppWinStyle.NormalNoFocus,true);
```

These two approaches didn't work to me because the processes (or the action of start and end the process) are stealing the focus from any application. I can't do anything when my application is running.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting a process without stealing focus (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121911/starting-a-process-without-stealing-focus-c)

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
```

Into:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

You don't seem to need `UseShellExecute` in your example, as you're running an executable directly and thus do not need the shell in this case.

Please note however that changing `UseShellExecute` to false does have the following effects:

> When UseShellExecute is false, the WorkingDirectory property is not
>   used to find the executable. Instead, it is used only by the process
>   that is started and has meaning only within the context of the new
>   process. When UseShellExecute is false, the FileName property must be
>   a fully qualified path to the executable.

And don't use `myProcess.WaitForExit();` unless you really do want to wait for the process to exit.

> The WaitForExit() overload is used to make the current thread wait
>   until the associated process terminates. This method instructs the
>   Process component to wait an infinite amount of time for the process
>   and event handlers to exit. This can cause an application to stop
>   responding.

Also see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle.aspx) for more information about the `ProcessWindowStyle` enumeration and possible values.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

like [Johannes Kommer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8167378/4608491) doesn't work for me. Cause [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) said:

> To use Hidden, the UseShellExecute property must be true.

But I find out that `startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;` gives the same effect as `startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;`

---

### Hidden Solution

Here is the code that completely hide that Process's window:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "E:\ffmpeg.exe";

startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.Arguments = "-i \"E:\\Download\\Video\\Test\\20.mp4\" -ss 00:00:20 -vframes 1 \"E:\\Download\\Video\\Thumbs\\20.png\"";

using (var proc = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    proc.WaitForExit();
    //Beware, there is case the exe ask for user confirmation
    //But the the Process Windows is hidden, thus user can't choose Y/N
    //Thus the proc never exit.
}
```

The

```
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Can be replaced with

```
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

And the Process's Window is hidden, your focus isn't stolen. But problem raises when the Process asks for your confirmation (for example: Overwrite existing file [Y/N]?), but the window is hidden so you can't choose [Y/N], thus you're stuck. If you don't like this, read my Minimize Solution.

---

### Minimize Solution

The focus is still stolen, but it's minimized so it won't pop into your face, and when it asks for confirmation, you and open it and choose `Y`. Here is the code for minimize:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "E:\ffmpeg.exe";

startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
startInfo.Arguments = "-i \"E:\\Download\\Video\\Test\\20.mp4\" -ss 00:00:20 -vframes 1 \"E:\\Download\\Video\\Thumbs\\20.png\"";

using (var proc = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    proc.WaitForExit();
}
```