# How to Set Focus Back To Calling Form After Starting A Process (Chrome)

Tags: c#, winforms, process, focus

I open up a Chrome browser window from my program using Process.Start() but the new opened chrome browser tab(s) covers the screen. But I want my application to maintain its focus after creating these chrome browser tab(s).

I will have one brower window open but several chrome tabs showing different URLs.

Here is what I've tried which is similar to the answer at [How to set focus back to form after opening up a process (Notepad)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881038/how-to-set-focus-back-to-form-after-opening-up-a-process-notepad). But doesn't work for me.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd)

// this code will get called several times with a different URL in Arguments property

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Chrome.exe");
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

p.StartInfo.Arguments = "https:/google.com";
p.Start();

p.WaitForInputIdle();
SetForegroundWindow(this.Handle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding a short delay seemed to work fine for me:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenUrl("https:/google.com");
}

private async void OpenUrl(string url)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Chrome.exe");
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = url;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForInputIdle();
    await Task.Delay(50);
    SetForegroundWindow(this.Handle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you SO much Idle_Mind. It works perfectly and has been plaguing me for several month, :-)