# Why do I get file not found excpetion with Interaction.Shell method?

Tags: c#, vb.net, shellexecute, interaction

I want to open a notepad file using `VisualBasic.Interaction.Shell` method. At present I get a file not found exception using the following code.

```
int pid = Interaction.Shell(@"D:\abc.txt", AppWinStyle.NormalNoFocus, false, -1);
```

But this works:

```
int pid = Interaction.Shell(@"notepad.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalNoFocus, false, -1);
```

Which just opens a notepad file. Why is this?

I do need it to open a file in a specific location. I see some advantage with Interaction.Shell execution. How is it possible to open a file in a specific location using Interaction.Shell?

Comment: Shell() is the same thing as Process.Start() with ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false.  Which means you can only start executable programs, not documents.  Use the Process class.

Comment: @HansPassant I was trying to cover the same problem of Notepad taking the focus when starting it like process.Start(). VB handles it so well. Got it from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121911/starting-a-process-without-stealing-focus-c .Also solution by the answerer here tackles it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as if `Interaction.Shell` cannot open an application by an associated document. (a) the relevant [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.shell%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) does not say so (although the example for the `PathName` parameter seems missleading then) and (b) even if `D:\abc.txt` does exist, it fails.

Alternatively you can use the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class:

```
using (Process process = Process.Start(@"D:\abc.txt"))
{
    int pid = process.Id;

    // Whether you want for it to exit, depends on your needs. Your
    // Interaction.Shell() call above suggests you don't.  But then
    // you need to be aware that "pid" might not be valid when you
    // you look at it, because the process may already be gone.
    // A problem that would also arise with Interaction.Shell.
    // process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Note that `D:\abc.txt` must exist, or you still get a `FileNotFoundException`.

**Update** If you really do need to use `Interaction.Shell`, you can use the following

```
int pid = Interaction.Shell(@"notepad.exe D:\abc.txt", false, -1);
```

Personally, I would go with the `Process` class, as it generally provides more robus handling of the launched process. In this case it also frees you from "knowing" which program is associated with `.txt` files (unless you always want to use `notepad.exe`).

Comment: Perfect solution. I have a problem of Notepad taking the focus when opening it like process.Start() from my winforms app. Which you can catch here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881038/how-to-set-focus-back-to-form-after-opening-up-a-process-notepad