# How can I open a web page from a WinForms app, while keeping the browser in the background?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I'm currently writing in C#, and I normally open links in the system default browser like this: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.link.com");`

This is definitely what I want most of the time. However, I also want to implement a little feature where if the user middle-clicks on a link in my UI, I open that link in the background and my app stays on top, so the user can open many links in a row. (Basically I want to do something similar to what browsers do with middle click, but I am not the browser.)

The best hack I can think of is to set `Form.TopMost = true` before opening the page and then unset it one second later, but that seems like a pretty crappy solution, and it would prevent a fast user from bringing up the browser in that time. Can anyone suggest something less hacky?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121911/starting-a-process-without-stealing-focus-c This is what your looking for

Answer (score 1):

after opening the webPage use `this.Focus();` in your code

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it, even if I sleep a few seconds to allow the browser to fully load. Is `Focus` intended more for moving around input focus within an app?

Comment: @JackO'Connor: create a new thread and on it use `thread.Sleep` and after that have `this.Focus();`

Comment: @JackO'Connor: did you tried to use `thread.Sleep` and then use `this.Focus();` in main thread?