# How do I open a process so that it doesn't have focus?

Tags: c#, process, automation

I'm trying to write some automation to open a close a series of windows (non-hidden, non-malicious) and I don't want them to steal focus as they open. The problem is that when each window opens, it steals focus preventing me from working while it runs in the background.
Here's the code that I execute in a loop to open the various windows:

```
using (Process proc = new Process())
{
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    proc.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    if (!proc.HasExited)
    {
        proc.Kill();
    }
}
```

How do I make these open without focus so I can do other things while this automation runs?

**Addenda:**
The program that is executing the above code is a simple console app.  The processes I'm starting are GUI apps.  For testing/designing purposes, I'm currently attempting this with repeated instances of Internet Explorer (`iexplore.exe`) with different arguments.

I will be running this and carrying on with other unrelated work while this runs in the background.  I don't want focus returned to the parent app, either.  Essentially, I'll run this `.exe` when I get to my desk, and switch to other windows to do other work, ignoring the original program and its child processes until it's finished.

Comment: Are you running this in the same thread as the rest of your application? Is it running within a WinForms or WPF application?

Comment: What kinds of processes are these?  Are they console apps, GUI applications?

Comment: Well you could take it back, but given the code sample you've provided unless you are running it in another thread, the code to take it back won't execute until your loop has finished anyway...

Comment: The app I'm running is a console app.  The apps I'm trying to open are full stand-alone GUI apps.  I've updated my question to mention that.

Comment: Does focus need to go back to your console shell, or to whatever program had focus before the new process was started?

Comment: Oh, and a nice no-code solution to this problem that I've used in the past: When doing automated testing of a web application I had a program that would, at times, frequently need to open a new browser/window but that ran for a long time.  Rather than try to deal with it stealing focus all of the time and making the workstation unusable, I ran it from a virtual machine so that it would only make that VM unusable, and leave the host machine (and other VMs) usable while it ran.  I could also still observe it's progress whenever I felt like it by looking into the VM (duel monitors rock here).

Comment: @Servy, to whatever process was in focus at process start. The intent is to start this task and let me carry on with unrelated work as it does its magic in the background.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting a process without stealing focus (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121911/starting-a-process-without-stealing-focus-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

The solution I ended up using circumvents any attributes or reassigning focus.  Since the task was automated and stand-alone, I just used the Windows Task Scheduler to run the application.  For whatever reason, as long as the "parent" console window isn't in focus, the "child" GUI windows open normally but not in focus—allowing me to continue working in another window while the application runs.

Comment: The code I used to start the process is in the question. This answer states that I used Windows Task Scheduler. There's no code for that. What code are you asking for?

Comment: Did you used the Windows Task Scheduler manually? I thought you used c# to create a Task in the Scheduler and ran it programatically. From what I gather its possible but not very well documented. I asked for that code. But If you did that manually I just misunderstood it.

Answer (score 18):

This is possible but only via pinvoke, which unfortunately requires about 70 lines of code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct STARTUPINFO
{
    public Int32 cb;
    public string lpReserved;
    public string lpDesktop;
    public string lpTitle;
    public Int32 dwX;
    public Int32 dwY;
    public Int32 dwXSize;
    public Int32 dwYSize;
    public Int32 dwXCountChars;
    public Int32 dwYCountChars;
    public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
    public Int32 dwFlags;
    public Int16 wShowWindow;
    public Int16 cbReserved2;
    public IntPtr lpReserved2;
    public IntPtr hStdInput;
    public IntPtr hStdOutput;
    public IntPtr hStdError;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    public IntPtr hProcess;
    public IntPtr hThread;
    public int dwProcessId;
    public int dwThreadId;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool CreateProcess(
    string lpApplicationName,
    string lpCommandLine,
    IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
    IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
    bool bInheritHandles,
    uint dwCreationFlags,
    IntPtr lpEnvironment,
    string lpCurrentDirectory,
    [In] ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
    out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

const int STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 1;
const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4; 
const int SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7; 


public static void StartProcessNoActivate(string cmdLine)
{
    STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
    si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

    CreateProcess(null, cmdLine, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true,
        0, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi);

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

Set `si.wShowWindow` to `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE` to show the window normally but without stealing focus, and `SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE` to start the app minimised, again without stealing focus.

A full list of options is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This works for me, though I had to add CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE to the CreateProcess call.  I'm grateful because the focus stealing was driving me nuts.

Comment: @EdBayiates Can you show how you implemented the CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE flags? I tried it as a value of 10 in the 6th parameter of CreateProcess and my execution is still showing to the forefront.

Comment: @Valamas-AUS const int CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010; and CreateProcess(appName, cmdLine, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, IntPtr.Zero, basePath, ref si, out pi);

Comment: Are there any wrapper libraries available for this?

Comment: Edit: I made one [here](https://github.com/jmbeach/betterprocess/blob/master/tests/BetterProcessTests/StartProcessTests.cs) that mimics System.Diagnostics.Process

Answer (score 2):

You can move focus to your app

```
    [DllImport("User32")]
    private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
    [DllImportAttribute("User32.DLL")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);


 Process.Start("");
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        var myWindowHandler = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
        ShowWindow(myWindowHandler, 5);
        SetForegroundWindow(myWindowHandler);
```

[SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This will restore focus to the "parent" app, correct?  I'd prefer that didn't happen either. I will be doing other work while this is running. (I've added a little more to my original question to make that more clear.)

Comment: Unless I did something wrong, using `GetForegroundWindow` before `Process.Start`, then `ShowWindow` and `SetForegroundWindow` to restore focused window didn't work either. This is strange.

Comment: This does not solve the problem to let the focus where it was before when the program which starts the processes is not the program with the focus.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian,
This is exactly what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

***`SetForegroundWindow` do the trick also in console apps.***

**Tested code:**

Create a simple class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    public void doProcess(string filename, string arguments){

        using (Process proc = new Process())
        {
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            proc.Start();

            SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the `main` method of your console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       MyClass mc = new MyClass();
       mc.doProcess("iexplore.exe", "http://www.stackoverflow.com");

       Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will restore focus to the "parent" app, correct?  I'd prefer that didn't happen either. I will be doing other work while this is running. (I've added a little more to my original question to make that more clear.)

Answer (score -2):

Use a combination of `Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true` and `Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`.

It might also be worth using `Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false`, and redirecting StdIn/StdOut/StdErr.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx

Comment: 1) these aren't console apps, they are GUI apps. 2) The requirements say they can't be hidden.

Answer (score -3):

I haven't tried this, but I believe if you set [proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle.aspx) = WindowStyle.Minimized that should do the trick.

Comment: does it actually minimize but steal the focus for the split second while its opening?

Comment: It appears to start the process(es) minimized and in focus.  If I'm typing in another window, I lose focus when the new process appears (only) on the task bar.