# How to launch an external MP3 player without taking focus?

Tags: c#, windows

I am writing a desktop C# app to manage my MP3 library (it's essentially a bulk MP3 tag editor) and I want to be able to play songs while working on the library.

I do not want to embed a music player into my app and I am happy with whatever my system has configured to play music (in my case I have Groove Music set as a default player on Windows 10).

Launching a song is easy: simply call `Process.Start(songPath);`. The trouble is that Groove Music steals focus which is annoying because it breaks my work flow.

How can I launch an external music player so that it plays in the background and doesn't steal focus?

I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/19049930/497403 with the following command lines:

- cmd.exe *songPath*
- "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" *songPath*

However, in both cases the music player window (Grove in the first case, Media Player in the second) still comes into foreground and steals focus.

I suppose I could, as a workaround, just embed Windows Media Player ActiveX in my app, but I'm still curious why I cannot get WMPlayer to start without grabbing focus, with SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE/SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE and what-not.

Comment: Maybe try setting your application's focus again, once you Groove Music starts?

Comment: [Foreground activation permission is like love: You can’t steal it, it has to be given to you](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090220-00/?p=19083).

Comment: Have you checked your code is running as expected if for example you simply start notepad.exe? The flag you put in the startupinfo is only enforced for the first window the app is showing. From the docs of ShowWindow: *'This parameter is ignored the first time an application calls ShowWindow, if the program that launched the application provides a STARTUPINFO structure. Otherwise, the first time ShowWindow is called, the value **should** be the value obtained by the WinMain function in its nCmdShow parameter'*.

Comment: Media Player steals focus with the SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE flag both the first time it launches and when it's already running (e.g. playing another song).

Comment: But does your code run as expected with notepad? Just to make sure you don't have a bug in it.

Comment: Good point. Yes, code runs as expected. ProcessHelper.StartProcessNoActivate("notepad.exe") launches Notepad in the background, whereas ProcessHelper.StartProcessNoActivate($"\"{player}\" \"{path}\"") pops media player into the foreground.

Comment: So MP simply ignores that flag. Let me try something out...

Comment: I was able to achieve only a half-success by using [LockSetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-locksetforegroundwindow). Not sure if it helps on your system.

Comment: I guess since the Windows media players are misbehaving themselves, everything I try would be a hack that may or may not work. I can either just give up or embed the player - not the most horrible solution, really.